# PHP File Input Validation

Tags: php, validation, file-upload

How can I create a function in PHP that checks if a file input is selected? The following is what I have but its not working.

Thank you!

```
function mcFileUp($mcFile){
    if(empty($_FILES[$mcFile]['name'])){
        echo 'empty';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Ok!';
    }
}
```

I figured it out:

```
function mcFileUp($mcFile){
    if(empty($mcFile))
    {
        echo 'empty';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Ok!';
    }
}

mcFileUp($_FILES['mcFileUpload']['name']);
```

Comment: 1. What is the code for the form uploading the file? 2. Can you show var_dump($_FILES)?

Comment: By "selected" do you mean "populated"?

Comment: You could probe for `['tmp_name']` instead, which only contains a filename after succeeded uploads.

Comment: I just want to check if the file input field is empty or a file has been selected.

Comment: What is the "file input field"?  Are the files already on the server?  Are you uploading a file selected from the user's computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
function mcFileUp($mcFile)
{
    if(strlen($_FILES[$mcFile]['name'])==0)
    {
        echo 'empty';
    }
    else 
    {
    echo 'Ok!';
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass the file name to this? mcFileUp($_FILES['mcFileUpload']['name']); This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The file name is automatically stored in the $_FILES['blah']['name'] if a file is selected.I just tried this and worked for me.The 'blah' is replaced by the `name` in the `form`

Comment: Sorry,i saw the function call in the comment just now.The function mcFileUp must be invoked by passing only the `name` attribute that was specified in the html form.for eg if your form is `<input type=file name=uploadedFile>` then the function call must be `mcFileUp('uploadedFile')`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES["uploaded_file"]))
{
   if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0))
   {
    ............
   }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
```

Comment: The problem is I need a function so I can plug in any file input field.

Comment: Create a functio with checking same conditions....and return 0 or 1 accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Check [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) page if you want to know props and corns about the `superglobal array "$_FILE"`. Also, you can have a look @ [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) tutorial. Hope it helps you...